# Symfony. Get the last object loaded

Tags: symfony

I have a situation where i must use an entity for persistence and associations with many other entities in several forms.

For example :

Entities `A,B,C` and `D`

Relation between A (supposing I want to use the entity `A` with `id 10`) and `B` is `oneToMany`.

How to get the `entity A` with `Id 10` in the controller of the `entity B` when creating a new `entity` `B`  ( `b->setA(A)` )

Knowing that i load the entity A only in one form by search

Or how to use loaded `entity A` with `Id 10` and use it in others controllers

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first controller where entity A is created and therefore you presumably have access to the id:

```
$this->get('session')->set('entityAId' => $entityA->getId());
```

In the second controller:

```
$entityAId = $this->get('session')->get('entityAId');
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entityA = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:EntityA')->findOneBy(array('id' => $entityAId));
```

You will need to cater for the scenario where no entity with that id is found and if you haven't used the session before you should read about [Symfony Session Management](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html)

Comment: Yes, but i do not now exactly the id ( 10 is just an example ) i get the entity  A only once in an separated form

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how to pass data between controllers via the session.

Comment: Ok thank you, iI thought that there was an other way to save an object. but session seems good.